# Csvhelper how to create custom Headers with Localization?

Tags: c#, csv, csvhelper

I am trying to create a csv with Headers that are going to be use in Multiple languages. this is the current Code that i am using and works for English but not for Japanese as example.

What is the best way to do that? should i have to specify the Culture Info? i tried that but not good results.

Thanks.

```
    private byte[] WriteCsvToMemory(IEnumerable records)
    {
        using (var memoryStream = new MemoryStream())
        using (var streamWriter = new StreamWriter(memoryStream, Encoding.UTF8))
        using (var csvWriter = new CsvWriter(streamWriter))
        {
            csvWriter.WriteField(GetResourceFileValue("ja-jp", "KEY")); 
            csvWriter.NextRecord();
            csvWriter.Configuration.HasHeaderRecord = false;
            csvWriter.WriteRecords(records);
            streamWriter.Flush();
            return memoryStream.ToArray();
        }
    }
```

Comment: Can you describe what specifically is happening? "not good results" isn't specific. Is there an exception being thrown? Is the header not written at all?

Comment: No Errors, it just does not Display Japanese characters. Works for English and Spanish without any problems.

Comment: What doesn't display Japanese characters? There is no code to display anything here.

Comment: The .csv File that is created by using this code on the Headers Part does not add the UNICODE characters. I am using an API so the next piece of code is to return the HttpResponseMessage with the content out of that funtion.

Answer (score 1):

i made a mistake on my code the solution is simple:

```
    using (var streamWriter = new StreamWriter(memoryStream, **Encoding.UTF8** ))
```

Nothing wrong with the the library.